# jquery human triggered events - event.pageX and event.pageY are undefined

Tags: jquery

I have mouseenter event attached for an element which is working fine. for the same event, triggering event manually using jQuery.trigger("mouseenter"). this is calling mouseenter handler. but in the event object, event.pageX and event.pageY are undefined. is there any way to get it?

created a sample -  [here](http://jsbin.com/igodeb/1/edit)

Comment: What do you expect the event.pageX and event.pageY to be if you triggered it manually? Since the mouse had no part in the event, there's no data for it's location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `mousemove` handler to keep track of the current mouse position. Then you can pass the x and y to `.trigger()` and they will be passed to your handler.

Comment: Thank you for helping me. isn't it a bug in jquery library?. while jQuery creating a event, why don't it consider the current mouse pointer also?.

Comment: My first guess is that if you want to explicitly trigger a mouse event, you might also want explicit control over the x/y coordinates received by the handler.